# AngularJS view not updating when model changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a $rootScope variable like this:

```
$rootScope.queue = {'A1':{'Name':'John','ID':'A1'},'A2':{'Name':'Anna','ID':'A2'}};
```

In my controller I have a function like this where update is an object from the queue with more recent data:

```
$scope.onMessage = function(update) {
    angular.extend($rootScope.queue[update['ID']], update);
};
```

The more recent data comes from an external application that sends the data to my application using the Google Channel API. Here is the code in the same controller:

```
channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('<?php echo $token ?>');
socket = channel.open();
socket.onmessage = $scope.onMessage;
```

My issue is, if I am viewing a person in the queue in my view e.g. John and I receive an update like(First name correction):

```
{'Name':'Jon','ID':'A1'}
```

The $rootScope.queue is updated correctly however my view does not update unless I re-click the person.

For my view I have something like (setActive() sets a $scope variable called active to the ID):

```
<div ng-controller="queueController">
    <div name="people" ng-model="people">
        <div ng-repeat="people in queue" ng-click="setActive(people.ID)">{{ people.Name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-model="queue">You clicked {{ queue[active].Name }}</div>
</div>
```

It was my understanding that in AngularJS if the data in queue changed my view would update also. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try running rootscope.$apply(); ?

Comment: @Beri Where and when do I run this?

Comment: @Craig in onMessage(), after you have modified the scope behind the back of AngularJS. Read its documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks that works. How am I modifying the scope behind the back of AngularJS? The code is in the controller function. Is it because I am using angular.extend? if so how do I do this so AngularJS will automatically pick up the changes?

Comment: You're modifying an object after an event that happens without AngularJS being aware of it (google channel messages are not handled by AngularJS). So Angular has no way to know that the object has been modified, and thus doesn't reevaluate all the expressions used in the view. All this is explained in the documentation.

Comment: Ah ok so an action has to occur on the view for it to update. I thought AngularJS watched the functions of the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that using ng-model="queue" was creating a $scope.queue instead of using the $rootScope.queue

To solve this I can define the queue like so:

```
$rootScope.myapp.queue = {'A1':{'Name':'John','ID':'A1'},'A2':{'Name':'Anna','ID':'A2'}};
```

And then use ng-model="myapp.queue"